# python installed but not recognised by zsh

Tags: python, zsh

I am using a Catalina macOS. I previously was able to work with my python installations with ease on this system. But today after updating other packages, such as wget and julia, I have encountered these errors `zsh: command not found: python3.8` on my terminal. Following suggestions on [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674445/export-of-pythonpath-from-zshrc-not-working) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423609/problems-using-zsh-with-catalina-python-python3-pip-pip3-path-zshrc-etc) I have tried to modify the PATH and zshrc but none of these approaches enables me to solve my problem.
I would be grateful if you can share your suggestions on how to deal with this issue.

Here are some of the outputs of my system.

zshrc:

```
vi ~/.zshrc

alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.8
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/shasa/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
if [ -f "/Users/shasa/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
    . "/Users/shasa/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
else
    export PATH="/Users/shasa/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

python:

```
which python
python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3.8
```

PATH:

```
echo $PATH 
/Users/shasa/anaconda3/bin:/Users/shasa/anaconda3/condabin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

Edit 1: In `/usr/local/bin/`, I can see that python3@, python3.9@ and python3.8@* are present. Do you think the extra * near python3.8@ can cause this problem? If yes, how can resolve that?

Comment: and have you checked `file /usr/local/bin/python3.8`?

Comment: Yes! The path seems correct as I can see python3.8@* in this directory.

Comment: have you `source ~/.zshrc` after you edited it?

Comment: yeah, I did that.

Comment: `@` means it is a symlink, that doesn't guarantee that the linked file is present. check with `readlink -f /usr/local/bin/python3.8`

Comment: @Shasa : If you manually invoke `/usr/local/bin/python3.8 --version` instead of `python --version`, what do you get?

Comment: @hjpotter92 with `-n` instead of `-f` I get: `../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3.8%`

Comment: @user1934428 I am getting `zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/python3.8`. I have already reinstall python3.8 using `brew`

Comment: @Shasa : Well, then you have your bug!  hjpotter92 was right after all. It means that _brew_ did not install Python to where you hope it would do. Now you have two options: Either you can find out where your Python installation ended up (and then fix your alias), or you can't (and then post this problem at [superuser](https://superuser.com/), because it is then off-topic at SO).

Comment: I see. Good to notice that. Thanks, @hjpotter92 and @user1934428!

Comment: @user1934428 you can also use the shortcut `[su]` for it to auto-expand to [su]. :) same for `[so]`, `[sf]` just in case you didn't know

Comment: @hjpotter92 :  No, I didn't! Very helpful indeed!

Comment: @Shasa "Following the discussion in the comments, I have found the source of the problem." Please put your solution into an answer and then accept your own answer. That way, your question doesn't stay open as unresolved _and_ if anyone else in future has the same problem, they will be able to find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the discussion in the comments, I have found the source of the problem. I run `brew doctor` and indeed found out that the python3.8 symlinks were broken. I have then removed broken symlinks by `brew cleanup` and reinstalled that again.